# File processing sorting and remove duplicate

Tags: linux, shell

I am new bee to the Linux environment. I have golden gate generated file as listed in the below format, using BELL character `^G` as a separator.

```
I^G2017-06-27 21:57:57.000000^G2^Gtest@gmail.com
I^G2017-06-27 22:00:04.000000^G2^Gtest@gmail.com
I^G2017-06-27 22:00:59.000000^G2^Gtest@gmail.com
K^G2017-06-27 23:00:09.000000^G2^Gtest123@gmail.com
```

First two columns are for internal representation to help sort and third column is unique key. that is based on the second column (time stamp) and third column... i want to sort the record and write the latest unique record to other file as given below.

```
2^Gtest123@gmail.com
```

Could you please help me on this. Thanks

Comment: You should show your code and state where you are having problems. Otherwise, you risk the wrath of the community for trying to use the site as a code writing service.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sort`, `cut` and `tail` to accomplish this:

```
sort -u -k2,2 -t^G input.txt | cut -d^G -f3,4 | tail -n1 > /tmp/output.txt
```

First, we tell sort select only unique rows (`-u`), to sort on the second column (`-k2,2`), to use the bell character as the separater (`-t^G`, type `ctrl+V` `ctrl+G` to type the character), and give it the input file. We then pipe the outout to `cut` using the same delimiter (`-d^G`) and to only keep the 3rd and 4th columns (`-f3,4`). We then pipe it to `tail -n1` outputing only the last line, and finally redirecting that to your output file.

Note that if you print `^G` to `stdout`, it won't display anything, but rather make your computer beep.